# Is NFC (Near Field Communication) technology open source?

Tags: nfc, wireless

I would like to know what specifically is considered NFC technology and whether there are any open source implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as open source technology. Open source relates to some implementation. The technology itself is standardized and open. Anyone can implement it in whatever way he likes, open or closed source, as long as it complies with the specifications.